# What's the cause of this potential memory leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

The line below gives me a "potential memory leak" when I analyze the program. I'm running the latest version of xCode (4.2) and the program runs without errors and has never crashed after much testing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance

```
[self.topTenEntry1 setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reddishcolor.tiff"]]];
```

Answer (score 7):

You are leaking the UIColor object. You initialise it but don't have a pointer to it to release.

Either create it beforehand and release it after, or autorelease in your line above.

```
self.topTenEntry1 setBackgroundColor:[[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reddishcolor.tiff"]]] autorelease];
```

Note that a memory leak does not necessarily cause your program to crash - if the leaking code is not executed very often, you will not notice much (except a vague sense of programmer's discomfort) during running. However, they should always be removed - especially straightforward ones like this. iOS is a memory constrained environment. The analyser picked this leak up straight away, there is no reason that Apple wouldn't also notice it during review.